# ARReferenceImage automatically resizes

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm trying to implement the image recognition feature from ARKit. I clicked the photo of my object (a book) on my iPhone X and added it as an ARReferenceImage to the Xcode project. When I try to mention the physical size of my image - (14.5cms x 26.5cms [width vs height]), Xcode always the changes the value of the other dimension.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What size is the output? Can you show your code? Then we can help :)

Comment: I've measured the size of my book as 14.5cms x 26.5cms. I'm trying to add that as the size in Xcode for the ARReferenceImage. When I try to set 14.5cms as the width, it automatically sets the value of the height's dimension and vice-versa. 

What code would you like?

Comment: In my case, it always tries to maintain a 4:3 (height: width) ratio.

Comment: I just create an image which is 14.5x26.5cm in Adobe Illustrator and was able to set the size accurately.

Comment: What dimensions do you get?

Comment: Im guessing that whilst your book is that size, the actual image itself is not?

Comment: What size am I supposed to specify? Straight from the documentation - "For each reference image, use the Xcode inspector panel to provide the real-world size at which you want ARKit to recognize the image."

Are these the dimensions of the object itself? Or the dimensions of the image (which is way smaller than the size of the object (obviously))

Comment: When you entered your size what did Xcode change the values to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166139/discussion-between-josh-robbins-and-kunal-shah).

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of testing myself, it looks like there could be an issue with your image ratio. I would suggest you try to resize the image in Adobe Illustrator to the same ratio as the books size as I'm guessing that the image taken with your `iPhoneX` has a different ratio.

For example I created an Image in `Adobe Illustrator` at exactly the same size that you specified and when placed in the `Assets` folder I entered 14.5cm for the width and it adjusted the height to 26.437cm, which whilst not exactly the same is near enough I would say.

What I did notice however, was that you could only change the size of the image by the ratio of the image provided.

So for example I created an image 5x5cm, and was able to set it to 30x30cm without issue, but not 30x10cm (which had a different ratio).

As such I believe (although I couldn't find it in the documentation) that your image must have the same aspect ratio as the 'real world object' you intend to track, so that you can enter it's physical size.

Perhaps this is a bug, or perhaps we are both missing something...

I appreciate this doesn't solve your problem per se, but might be useful to someone else.

Comment: In my case, it always tries to maintain a 4:3 (height: width) ratio.

Comment: I understand that. But what size am I supposed to enter?